# how do i re-enable the accent key in Lubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout

i use a latin american keyboard layout, with Ñ key included and working. since upgrading to 16.04, the key beside the letter P, which allows for typing accented vowels, does not work. pressing it + a vowel doesn't return á, é, í, ó or ú, just the vowel itself. how can i re-enable the dead key? there is no "latin american, with dead keys" option in my keyboard settings. thank you!

Comment: What button is next to the P key? There are quite a few different keyboard layouts. Since I use QWERTY US I assume it's the `[`/`{` key.

Comment: i'm sorry for not clarifying--the latin american keyboard layout has the ¨ / ´ characters on that key.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the layout from the [panel](http://fahadahammed.com/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout-in-lxde/).  System / Settings / Keyboard and then choosing the Layout tab should work as well.

Comment: that is what i have done. it is set as spanish, latin american already. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by clicking System Settings, Keyboard, Layouts, Options, and selecting Key_to_Choose_3rd_Level and setting Any_Alt_Key, then Alt-(vowel) will give áéíóú.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i've solved this  a long time ago. i set the keyboard as "spanish, latin american" and all worked as i intended it to.